# TFS Test Manager creating different WIT than bug

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, microsoft-test-manager, workitem

In my company, with our ISO 9001 certification, we have two different ways to manage bugs. We have Bug as Deliverable (BaD) and Bug as Task (BaT). The BaD is created during our agile process during the "test by client" phase, when the client create a bug in his backlog. The BaT is created during quality control phase and is added as a Task in the current deliverable. Both BaD and BaT have pretty much the same WIT definition (both have the reprosteps, acceptence criteria, and such, but they still are two different entities since ISO steps are not the same for deliverable and tasks (a task is code reviewed and a deliverable as analysis and quality control steps). So the current TFS Bug WIT is the BaD and we created BugTask WIT for the BaT.

So my question is: *Is there a way to make Test Manager able to create a **BugTask** instead of a **Bug**?* or is it possible to create somehting else than a bug using Test Manager. (currently using Test Manager 2015, but I have no problem to go with 2017 if I have the possibility with it).

At the moment, what I do is *Create a bug from result*, copy the reprostep section and paste it in my bugtask, but if I could automated that process instead, I would be very pleased.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it's basically just "Bug".

Comment: The Test and Feedback client for Chrome that integrates into VSTS does allow you to create different kinds of work items. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/test-feedback/gnldpbnocfnlkkicnaplmkaphfdnlplb

Comment: @jessehouwing Well, it's locked at 3 kind of creation: 1.bugs, 2.tasks, 3.test cases. It sure is useful for exploratory test of web application, but it's not quite what I'm looking for.